# How to Create a Recommended Test Planning in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, tdd

Goal:
Make lots of different test for a specific stored procedure named 'sp_test' in order to review if you are retrieving the same data based on data input.

Purpose:
If you have made lots of changes in the stored stored 'sp_test' and you need to make validation if this SP works perfectly before using it in production phase. I need to make a lot of test. There are at least 20 different test. The code below is a simplified version.

Problem:
Do you have a recommended solution or approach how to create it?
My request is to retrieve a table that display the column testnumber, Parameter and Result.  (The column Result displays 'Passed' or Failed)

The testlist is below.

I see this approach the same way as TDD.

Thanks!

Test list

> Test number 1:
>   Parameter 'Science'
>   Hit: 5 rows
>   Hit is the correct answer from the SP
>
> Test number 2:
>   Parameter 'Programming'
>   Hit: 1 row
>   Hit is the correct answer from the SP
>
> Test number 3:
>   Parameter 'Computers'
>   Hit: 2 row
>   Hit is the correct answer from the SP
>
> Test number 4:
>   Parameter 'Business'
>   Hit: 1 row and BookID = 6
>   Hit 1 is correct and then review if BookID is 6 are correct answer from SP

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Books](
    [BookID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BookName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Category] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Price] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [Price_Range] [varchar](20) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [BookID] ASC )
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO dbo.Books 
    (BookName, Category, Price, Price_Range)
VALUES  
    ('Computer Architecture', 'Computers', 125.6, '100-150'),
    ('Advanced Composite Materials', 'Science', 172.56, '150-200'),
    ('Asp.Net 4 Blue Book', 'Programming', 56.00, '50-100'),
    ('Strategies Unplugged', 'Science', 99.99, '50-100'),
    ('Teaching Science', 'Science', 164.10, '150-200'),
    ('Challenging Times', 'Business', 150.70, '150-200'),
    ('Circuit Bending', 'Science', 112.00, '100-150'),
    ('Popular Science', 'Science', 210.40, '200-250'),
    ('ADOBE Premiere', 'Computers', 62.20, '50-100')

--------------

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test 
    @test nvarchar(50)

AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        [BookID],
        [BookName],
        [Category],
        [Price],
        [Price_Range]
    FROM [dbo].[Books]
    WHERE [Category] = @test

GO
```

Comment: As a trivial example of where this can go wrong, your example has no `ORDER BY` clause, hence the results may be returned in any order but are still correct. A more general case of testing stored procedures that modify the state of the database and cause triggers to fire ... might become complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this with a specific test framework, like tsqlt / Redgate SQL Test / VS unit tests / DBFit?  Or implementing something yourself?

If you are doing this manually, one option is a test config table with the parameter input values and expected output, then dynamically execute (sp_executesql) the procedure using the table values as inputs, followed by capturing and comparing the outputs.

Comment: I'm not using any test framework. 
If you have a concrete solution with SQL and SQL server, it would be create to see a sample of it.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to test - just rowcount match, exact output schema match (structure), structure & data, output parameters, all of the above?  I have created versions of all of the above at some point in time before using tools.

Comment: Today it is rowcount match, retrieve specfic data value. The rest of the thing that you have mention can be a possible in the future. How have you enable to solve it? Thanks!